# Swift: Add more data to TableView on Scroll & Delete No Longer Needed Data from the TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I am using parse server.

I have # of social media posts with data that I add to the tableview. Everything loads correctly. However, I have a massive amount of posts (50).

I only want to limit the tableview to have a max of 10, which I successfully use via query.limit. 
However, I would like to load the next 10 on the tableView once the user scrolls passed the last 10 of the series.

Additionally, I would like to delete the previous 10 of the series because this will take up too much data on my user's phone.

Comment: Perhaps it's best to load 10 and not delete any data? I am not a professional when it comes to determining parse strategy. I want to give my users an optimal experience.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against deleting the current items in the UITableView, as that's an abnormal design pattern and is likely to confuse your users. UITableViews and UICollectionViews are designed to reuse cells in order to be performant.

Here's how I would handle pagination. This example uses a UICollecitonView, but you should be able to apply the same logic with your tableview

```
var skip = 0
var loading = false
var fullyLoaded = false
var posts = [Post]()

func queryPosts(){
    guard !self.fullyLoaded else{return}
    guard !self.loading else{return}
    self.loading = true
    let query = Post.query()
    query?.limit = 10
    query?.skip = self.skip
    query?.findObjectsInBackground(block:{
        (posts, error) in
        for post in posts{
            self.posts.append(item)
        }
        self.skip = self.posts.count
        if posts.count == 0{self.fullyLoaded = true}
        self.loading = false
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(indexPath: indexPath) as PostCell
    cell.loadPost(self.posts[indexPath.item])

        if self.posts.count == indexPath.item - 1{
            self.queryPosts()
        }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree deleting would be irregular. I understand where you are coming from with your skip variable. I am not too familiar with guard {return statement}. What I will do is tell the query to skip post.count to retrieve the next 10 variables. However, can you explain how to create a function that when a user scrolls passed a certain point, it initiates this function again.

Comment: You can do it just like I did in the cellForItemAt function